# Column B's numerical values must be greater than Column A, given that Column A could have negative values, Data Validation in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two Columns A and B, when I key in a value in A1, and then proceed to key in a value in Column B, I want Column B to do a validation check on the input in Column B, making sure that the value in Column B is greater than the value in Column A, in numerical sense, but not in absolute values.

Often times, values in Column A are negative values, so I would like to find a custom formula which will take into account the negative signs.

For Example: when Column A has 100, Column B should be 102. When Column A has -100, Column B should have -102. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try data validation like below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the absolute function does not work well on the negative values. But it is fine! My colleague helped me address the issue already! Thank you once again :)